# Why do I get every title of each post when I filter them in single.php

Tags: php, wordpress, filtering, title

I am just working on filter titles in pages and posts and everything works as expected but when I view the single.php whereas it shows the actual post as should be, the function hook filter i am working on inside functions.php of my plugin is filtering every title of each post of my blog, I was expecting to filter just the title of the current post:

```
add_filter( 'the_title', 'ta_modified_post_title');
function ta_modified_post_title ($title) { 
    if((in_the_loop())){ 
      /**/
    }    
}
```

any help is grateful.

Thanks ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
add_filter( 'the_title', 'ta_modified_post_title');
function ta_modified_post_title ($title) { 
    if((some condition true)){ 
     $add_this = 'some string';
     $new_title = $title.' '.$add_this;
      return $new_title;
    }   

      return $title; 
}
```

when you view any post it is shown through single.php so every post becomes current post when you view it

Comment: I understand now that for the filter title hook it is the same viewing a single post from single.php than viewing the whole blog for filter. would there be a way of filtering with a condition to only retrieve the title of the current post in single.php?, I did try something like this but obviously I cant nest it.

Answer (score 0):

I understand now that for the filter title hook it is the same viewing a single post from single.php than viewing the whole blog. would there be a way of filtering with a condition to only retrieve the title of the current post in single.php?, I did try "get_the_title(get_the_ID())" like this but obviously I cant nest it.

```
add_filter( 'the_title', 'ta_modified_post_title');
function ta_modified_post_title ($title) { 
    if((in_the_loop())){ 
      if(is_single()){
        $title=get_the_title(get_the_ID());
      }
    }    
}
```